# Unable to train BiLSTM due to FailedPreconditionError

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, elmo

I am building a BiLSTM model using Elmo embeddings with TensorFlow Hub.

My code looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from keras.layers import Layer
import keras.backend as K

class ElmoEmbeddingLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.dimensions = 1024
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.elmo = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3', trainable=self.trainable, name="{}_module".format(self.name))
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        result = self.elmo(K.squeeze(K.cast(x, tf.string), axis=1),
                      as_dict=True,
                      signature='default',
                      )['default']
        return result

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return K.not_equal(inputs, '--PAD--')

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.dimensions)

input_text = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding = ElmoEmbeddingLayer()(input_text)
dense = Dense(256, activation='relu')(embedding)
pred = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense)
model = Model(inputs=[input_text], outputs=pred)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(train_text, 
          train_label,
          validation_data=(test_text, test_label),
          epochs=5,
          batch_size=32)
```

I am unable to train the model because of the error:

> FailedPreconditionError: Could not find variable elmo_embedding_layer_6_module/bilm/CNN_high_0/b_carry. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status error message=Resource localhost/elmo_embedding_layer_7_module/bilm/CNN/W_cnn_3/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist      [[{{node elmo_embedding_layer_7/elmo_embedding_layer_7_module_apply_default/bilm/CNN/Conv2D_3/ReadVariableOp}}]]

Can someone explain what the error means? I tried updating all modules, did not solve the issue

Comment: you have some indentation issues in your question

Comment: Yes, not pasted correctly. They should be resolved now